# VBA: can't get the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

```
Sub ExtractFeedbackStats()

Const Path As String ="C:\feedbackFiles_4analysis\"
Const fileExtension As String = "*.xlsx"

 'Variables
 Dim feedbackFile As Variant
 Dim analysisFile As Variant
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim Cell As Range
 Dim errorRange As Range
 Dim lastRow As Variant
 Dim counter As Integer
 Dim cellValue As Variant

'Target path with extension
 feedbackFile = Dir(Path & fileExtension)

 'Set constants
 firstRow = "2"
 errorColumn = "AG"

  'Loop through file error detail report, look at HARD_ERROR_CD column
  Do While feedbackFile <> ""

'Open each spreadsheet in folder
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & feedbackFile)
DoEvents

'Set parameters for scanning
lastRow = Range("E2").Value + 1

'Set data range to be scanned
Set errorRange = Range(errorColumn & firstRow, errorColumn & lastRow)

'Establish counter for error code instances
counter = 0

'Loop through each row in spreadsheet
For Each Cell In errorRange.Cells
    cellValue = Cell.Value
    
    'If: GR001 Error, Then: Return Customer Code + unique_counter
    If cellValue = "GR001" Then counter = 100

        Next Cell

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to the next line of code
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
DoEvents

'Get next file name
feedbackFile = Dir

'Close Loop
 Loop
 
 End Sub
```

I have a nearly identical piece of code in another module that uses the same FOR EACH Loop and can get the value of the cell that's being pointed at. But this one does not do it. Have tried playing around with all the variable types to get something to work, but can't get vba to recognize the data in the cell. What am I doing wrong here? Successful code looks like:

```
Sub FeedbackFilesExtract()

'Update this folder to local
 Const destPath As String = "C:\feedbackFiles_4analysis\"
 Const srcPath As String = "M:\Feedback\"

 'Variables
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim srcFile As Variant
 Dim destFile As Variant
 Dim File As Variant
 Dim fileArray() As Variant
 Dim dataRange As Range
 Dim Cell As Range
 Dim arrayCounter As Integer
 Dim counter As Integer

'Set data range
Set ws = Sheets("FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST")
secondColumn = "B"
firstRow = "2"
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set dataRange = Range(secondColumn & firstRow, secondColumn & lastRow)             

'Set size of array to accomodate list
ReDim fileArray(dataRange.Cells.Count)
                                                                        

'Populate array with list of files from xlsm
 For Each Cell In dataRange.Cells
        fileArray(arrayCounter) = Cell.Value
        arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
 Next Cell
```

Comment: "But this one does not do it" please be more specific.  A good start might be to fully-qualify all of your range references with a worksheet.

Comment: Please include the whole related `Sub` procedure code in OP.

Comment: Maybe the `feedbackfile` is empty. What are the contents of `Path` and `fileextension`

Comment: I guess no one can help you here as we don't have your data. I would suggest you use the debugger to execute your code step by step. Could be that `Dir` doesn't find anything (so that the outer loop is not entered at all) or that `errorRange` doesn't contain the data you expect (so that the inner loop is not entered or doesn't contain the data you are interested in). `lastRow = Range("E2").Value + 1`  looks strange to me: Do you really have the number of the last row stored in that cell?

Comment: `lastRow = Range("E2").Value + 1` which sheet is this on, and which workbook?  At that point `wb` is the ActiveWorkbook, so your code defaults to reading `lastRow` from there.  You *really* need to ensure that every call to `Range()`, `Cells()` etc is qualifies with a specific worksheet in a specific workbook, or you'll be forever chasing down bugs in your code.  Maybe review the guidelines here if you need help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams To clarify, the top macro does not work. The bottom macro works perfectly and follows the same logic for cell reference. The only difference is that the bottom macro is populating an array, the top macro seeks to populate a variable.

Comment: @TimWilliams indeed, wb is the workbook I intend to refer to.  Stepping through the program, the file references and variables are all correct. The only part that isn't working is that the variable cellValue does not populate with Cell.Value

Comment: @Blackcat the feedbackfile is not empty. The content of Path is the folder path that I want to look at. fileextension is the extension of the files i'm looking at

Comment: @FunThomas I used the debugger, that's how i know its the cell reference part that's failing. Dir is finding the files appropriately- they all get opened and observed. errorRange works and the inner loop gets entered. lastRow works too- it finds the last row of each workbook. I only added the plus one because there's a header on the sheet.. And it indeed finds the last row as intended. 
Like i said, everything works fine except the cell reference. that's what I'm trying to solve. No other issues, variables and file paths all are correct as shown in the debugger

Comment: Your code should work OK, so there's something we're not seeing, perhaps something odd about your source file.  Are you able to share that (suitably redacted) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share those contents. Imagine a folder whose only contents are excel reports that have been generated through SSRS, so the format is all the same. After reviewing your comments, I'm fairly certain that I'm not getting the results I want because of the sheet in each workbook that is being referenced. I will circle back and confirm that once I've tried a few other fixes that you guys n gals have inspired

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines need to be added:

```
    Next
Loop
```

Comment: Those are already on it. The loop works fine. it's the cell reference that is not.

Answer (score 0):

To define a range try this

```
Set errorRange = Range(errorColumn & firstRow & ":" & errorColumn & lastRow)
```

Comment: FYI, `.Range("A1:A2") = .Range("A1", "A2") = .Range("A1", lcell) = .Range(fcell, "A2") = .Range(fcell, lcell)`.

Comment: @vbas Thank you for this special info. In the future i will use it

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing Tim's comments, I realized that this was as simple as setting the active worksheet. Notice I had the 'ws' variable declared but hadn't used it; more or less a rookie mistake made in the tenth hour of the workday. I really appreciate all your guys' help. Even the proposed solutions that did not fix my issue still served as inspiration for efforts moving forward so thank you for your input and for bearing with me through this.

Comment: Do not keep unqualified object references 'laying' around: `Sheets(...)`, `Range(...)`, `Cells(...)`, `Rows(...)`, `Columns(...)`. Qualify the first with a workbook, and the others with a worksheet (the last three are also used with a range): `Set ws = wb.Sheets("FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST")`, `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`, `Set dataRange = ws.Range(secondColumn & firstRow, secondColumn & lastRow)`, `lastRow = ws.Range("E2").Value + 1`. Also, use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module. It will detect any undeclared variables (`firstRow`, `errorColumn`) and detect typos.